ESP32: Does PCB without copper affect the keep-out zone of the antenna?
Espressif recommends in their PCB Layout Design that the antenna is placed outside of the board, either top right or bottom right. Interestingly a placement to the top left or bottom left is not recommended:
Variant A
Now I wonder, if the antenna is not placed outside the PCB, if the raw PCB could have a significant bad effect to it, even if all copper (planes and traces) below the antenna and within a 15 mm clearance is removed:

Variant B
Would variant A be enough? Could the raw PCB have an impact, must it be cut out such as in variant B?


While I don't have an answer, air and PCB are two different materials with different RF properties, such as permittivity. Can it make a difference?

Usually such a device is put into a plastic case, so it is more the question if it makes a significant difference.

I'm guessing that the PCB material itself doesn't affect much. But having copper close to the left and top edge of the antenna, will. A or B as shown probably won't make much difference.

What they're telling you is not to have any copper or other conductor under or above the antenna itself.
